# Service invoked too many times for one day: tricreate

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making an app as part of Google summer of code, the app is running but I wanted to add an additional feature, this feature needs to create a number of spreadsheets and fill them with data, however somewhere in the middle I get an error:"Service invoked too many times for one day: tricreate. (line 19)". I understood that some services have limits and that is probably the reason, but I need help to understand how the limits "work" for spreadsheets in order to find a way to work around them, I guess it is time based, but is it on daily basis, hours, minutes?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you're hitting the limit for the number of Spreadsheets you can create in one day. There is a problem with the error message though; it should probably say something like spreadsheet create, rather than tricreate. I've created a bug in the issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1312. You can star it if you'd like to be updated when it's resolved.

We recently launched a Dashboard for Apps Script that has a tab for Quota Limits: https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard. Click the Quota Limits tab, and look for the row in the table called "Spreadsheet Create". Then you'll see the limits for number of spreadsheets that can be created per day for consumer (for example @gmail.com) accounts, Google Apps (free) accounts and Google Apps for Business/Education/Government accounts.